# Java - Problem with casting an int to char

Tags: java, casting, char, int

I have a bit of confusion regarding casting from int to char data type, this is what i have;

```
int k = 3;
System.out.println((char)k + " " + k)
```

The output should have been

```
3 3
```

yet, i got this instead

```
 3
```

Could somebody explains to me why is this happening?

Comment: To make sense of this I suggest you look at how ASCII works. https://ascii.cl/index.htm?content=mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers: If you know for sure that `0 <= k <= 9`, you can use

```
System.out.println((char)(k + '0'));
```

to print the 'charified' version of your integer.
If `k < 0` or `k > 9`, there isn't a single char (character) describing it. In that case, you'll have to use a string, which is basically an array of chars:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(k));
```

Answer (score 4):

The `char` '3' doesn't have a numeric value of 3. Its numeric value is 51.

This will print 3:

```
int k = 51;
System.out.println((char)k);
```

The `char` having a numeric value of 3 is an invisible character.

If you want to convert a single digit `int` to the corresponding `char`, you can write

```
int k = 3;
char three = (char)('0' + k);
System.out.println(three);
```

Comment: I see... Then how is the proper way to convert an int to char?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII value of `(char) 3` is :  *End of text*

If you want to get the numeric value you need to use numeric value 51 which is the ASCII value of 3:

```
int k = 51;
System.out.println((char) k + " " + k);
```

This gives output :

> 3 51

Complete ASCII table can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)